# Is it possible to use VPN extensions such as Hola in Chrome Apps?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, vpn

There are several Chrome extensions that acts like a VPN. An (in)famous example is `Hola`. If I change my IP using one of these, I will globally get a new IP address in Chrome.

However, the new IP is not reflected inside Chrome apps. On the other hands, a proxy like `FoxyProxy` does indeed also affects Chrome apps.

It is possible somehow to make the extension work inside my app, for example by changing the manifest etc?

Comment: Have you been able to checked about [`chrome.vpnProvider`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/vpnProvider)?

Comment: Yes, that is not an option in this specific case. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because the extensions work inside chrome and do not affect the global configuration of the system. You can find more info [here](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/1698338?hl=en&ref_topic=6238980)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).